# Is it possible to programmatically enforce a derived class to pass itself into a base class as the generic type?

Tags: c#, generics

Basically, I have the following scenario:

```
public abstract class FooBase<T> where T : FooBase<T>
{
    public bool IsSpecial { get; private set; }

    public static T GetSpecialInstance()
    {
        return new T() { IsSpecial = true };
    }
}

public sealed class ConcreteFooA : FooBase<ConcreteFooA> { ... }
public sealed class ConcreteFooB : FooBase<ConcreteFooB> { ... }
```

But, the problem I see here is that I could have done `ConcreteFooB : FooBase<ConcreteFooA> { ... }`, which would completely mess up the class at runtime (it wouldn't meet the logic I'm trying to achieve), but still compile correctly.

Is there some way I haven't thought of to enforce the generic, T, to be whatever the derived class is?

---

Update: I do end up using the generic parameter, T, in the `FooBase<T>` class, I just didn't list every method that has it as an out and in parameter, but I do have a use for T.

Comment: Throw an exception if `typeof(this) != typeof(T)`, in the constructor? Or are you looking for a compile time solution?

Comment: This is known as a Curiously Repeating Template Pattern or Curiously Repeating Generic Pattern.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth - Wasn't thinking that far ahead ;)

Comment: @Oded: And I didn't realize that `ConcreteFooA` is sealed ;)

Comment: What is the dependency on the derived type within your FooBase?

Comment: What the diddly? Are you trying to create an infinite improbability drive?

Comment: @JeffWatkins: This is commonly used in fluent interfaces that are not realized using extension methods.

Comment: @michael: Are you trying to create a fluent interface? If so, could you please show some of the methods that use `T`. An alternate approach would be to implement the fluent interface using extension methods. However, this would only work correctly of it would be possible to remove `T` completely from `FooBase`.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth thanks for the practical example. I see how it could be useful now!

Comment: @DanielHilgarth: I've expanded my `FooBase<T>` class to show the method of why I need the generic type T. I want to enforce it to be the same as it's base class because I don't want someone to be able to create a new ConcreteFooA using `ConcreteFooB.GetSpecialInstance()` to return a type of `ConcreteFooA`.

Comment: @michael: Using `ConcreteFooB.GetSpecialInstance()` is discouraged. static methods should be called on the class that define them, in your case `FooBase<ConcreteFooB>`. Which would make the whole problem go away.

Comment: @michael: When you're doing `ConcreteFooB.GetSpecialInstance()` you're really doing `FooBase<ConcreteFooB>.GetSpecialInstance()`, just an fyi.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your question:

No, there is no compile time solution to enforce this.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways to enforce this rule:

1. Unit Testing - You could write up a unit test (or unit tests) to ensure that the compiled types are passing themselves in as the generic parameter.
2. Code Analysis - You could create a custom code analysis rule that enforces this, and then set that rule as an error (vs warning). This would be checked at compile-time.
3. FxCop Rule - Similar to the Code Analysis rule, except if you don't have a version of Visual Studio that has built-in support for Code Analysis, then you can use FxCop instead.

Of course, none of these rules are enforced on a standard compilation, but instead require additional tools (Unit Testing, Code Analysis, FxCop). If someone took your code and compiled it without using these tools you'd run into the same issue... of course, at that point why is someone else compiling your code without running your unit tests or Code Analysis/FxCop rules?

---

Alternatively, and I don't recommend this, you could throw a run-time error. Why not? According to Microsoft:

> If a static constructor throws an exception, the runtime will not
>   invoke it a second time, and the type will remain uninitialized for
>   the lifetime of the application domain in which your program is
>   running.

That really doesn't solve your issue. On top of that, throwing an exception during static initialization is a violation of Code Analysis [CA1065:DoNotRaiseExceptionsInUnexpectedLocations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386039.aspx). So, you're going in the wrong direction if you do this.

Answer (score 1):

There is no compile-time way to enforce this, as far as I know. It can, however, be enforced using a run-time check. No unusual user actions would typically be able to cause this, (just incorrect coding) so it's similar to having `Debug.Assert` in places (and, in fact, you could implement it using that, if you like). E.g.

```
public abstract class FooBase<T> where T : FooBase<T>
{
    protected FooBase()
    {
        Debug.Assert(this.GetType() == typeof(T));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you have this as a requirement. I would first suggest that you go back and look at 'your object model and determine why you feel you need this requirement and determine if there's a better way to accomplish whatever it is you're trying to achieve.

I think I see one problem with what you have above: no generic parameters in your definitions/declarations of classes `ConcreteFooA` and `ConcreteFooB`.

It looks as though it may be better for you to create an interface `IFooBase` and have your concrete implementations implement the interface. In every instance where you want to work with an `IFooBase`, you'd use a variable of type `IFooBase`.

So:

```
public interface IFooBase { /* Interface contract... */ }

public class ConcreteFooA : IFooBase { /* Implement interface contract */ }
public class ConcreteFooB : IFooBase { /* Implement interface contract */ }

// Some class that acts on IFooBases
public class ActionClass
{
    public ActionClass(IFooBase fooBase) { this._fooBase = foobase };

    public DoSomething() { /* Do something useful with the FooBase */ }

    // Or, you could use method injection on static methods...
    public static void DoSomething(IFooBase fooBase) { /* Do some stuff... */ }
}
```

Just some ideas. But I don't think you can accomplish what you want to do with Generics alone.

Comment: This kind of class structure is commonly used in fluent interfaces.

Comment: I do have a use for T in the base class, I just didn't post all my methods in my base class and instead put the ellipse characters indicating there is stuff inside the class.

Comment: I see...hmm. Good point Daniel Hilgarth..`IQueryable` for one, I suppose ;) Duh..

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible and it should not be, because according to L in SOLID:

Liskov substitution principle: “objects in a program should be replaceable with instances of their subtypes without altering the correctness of that program”.

So actually the compiler is doing what it was meant to do.

Maybe you need to change the design and implementation of your classes for example by employing a Behavioral Pattern. For instance if an object should present different algorithms for a specific calculation you could use [Strategy Pattern](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternStrategy.aspx).

But I can not advise on that since I am not aware what exactly you want to achieve.